# How to access div element by jquery on iframe?

Tags: jquery, html

How to access div element by jquery on iframe?

I tried this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmxsw/5/))

```
<script>

    var ifr = $("#ifr");

    $("#ifr").load(function () {
        alert($("#ifr").contents().find('#test').html());
    });

    $("#ifr").attr('src', 'http://meoooh.raonnet.com/test/oh.html');

</script>
<iframe id="ifr" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

And

I get a `undefined` alert.

Why I can't access div element?

Comment: When it asks you to accompany your link with code, do it. Don't just try and find a workaround.

Comment: Did the find() call return something?

Answer (score 1):

> Why I can't access div element?

For security reasons. You can only access DOM elements of a child iframe if this iframe is pointing to the same domain as the parent page. In the example you have shown the parent page is hosted on `jsfiddle.net` whereas the `src` property of your iframe if pointing to `meoooh.raonnet.com` which are 2 different domains and browsers do not allow you to do that. Only if the 2 domains are the same you can access elements inside the iframe.

Comment: ... Only if the 2 domains `and subdomains and port and protocols used` are the same ...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome returns the following error in the console:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame
>   with origin "http://meoooh.raonnet.com". **Protocols, domains, and ports must match.**